# Add multi attribute in scenarios. Yii user

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to add multi attribute in scenarios. It is user_lastname, user_status.
It override user model

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();

    $scenarios['create'][]   = 'user_name'; 
    $scenarios['update'][]   = 'user_name'; 
    $scenarios['register'][] = 'user_name'; ;
    return $scenarios;
}
```

I sample but  I found a problem about array to string conversion

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    // add field to scenarios
    $scenarios['create'][]   = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 
    $scenarios['update'][]   = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 
    $scenarios['register'][] = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 
    return $scenarios;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove array `[]` from scenario list.

```
public function scenarios()
{
   $scenarios = parent::scenarios();

   // add field to scenarios
   $scenarios['create']   = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 
   $scenarios['update']   = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 
   $scenarios['register'] = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status']; 

   return $scenarios;
}
```

Use **const** to declare scenario names. For Example, `const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create'`;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append elements to existing array you need to add every item separately:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();

    $scenarios['create'][] = 'user_name'; 
    $scenarios['update'][] = 'user_name'; 
    $scenarios['register'][] = 'user_name';

    $scenarios['create'][] = 'user_lastname'; 
    $scenarios['update'][] = 'user_lastname'; 
    $scenarios['register'][] = 'user_lastname';

    $scenarios['create'][] = 'user_status'; 
    $scenarios['update'][] = 'user_status'; 
    $scenarios['register'][] = 'user_status';

    return $scenarios;
}
```

`$scenarios['create'][] = ['user_name','user_lastname','user_status'];` will just add one item as array.